# How can I make my custom onChanged in a function in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a function for API call. I used it's parameter listener for checking sent and received progress. Now, I want to add an onChanged function which listens to sent and received values and notify them when the function is called. Like:

```
void callThisAPI({header}) {
  _dio.request(
    onSendProgress(sent, total) {    //This is a listener which changes according to the data sent.
      double percent=1.0*sent/total;
      //I want to return this percent value back to where function is called and updated accordingly.
    }
  )
}

Now, when calling:

callThisAPI(
  header: someHeader
  onChanged(percentage) {
     progressPercentage=percentage
    //Here I want to receive  the percentage continuously when it changes.
  }
)
```

If the question is not clear enough, please do tell me if I should paste my code for more understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
void callThisAPI({header, void Function(double)? onChanged}) {
  _dio.request(
    onSendProgress(sent, total) {    //This is a listener which changes according to the data sent.
      double percent=1.0*sent/total;
      //I want to return this percent value back to where function is called and updated accordingly.
      onChanged?.call(percent);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: I did the exact same thing and it worked. Thanks